Netgear Switch SNMP OID for port physical status
I'm looking for an SNMP OID that provides a Netgear M4300 switch port's physical configuration/speed status.
I've found an entry in their private MIB, but it's marked as obsolete and based on my own testing, doesn't appear to be a populated value.
agentPortPhysicalStatus https://oid-rep.orange-labs.fr/get/1.3.6.1.4.1.4526.1.6.1.2.13.1.8
This entry describes the value as containing speed, but this OID offers more information than raw speed. Otherwise IF-MIB's ifSpeed value would suffice.
I assume this obsoleted value has been replaced by some other OID, but after reviewing the relevant private and public MIB's, I've been unsuccessful in finding one. I've also used snmpwalk to compare change deltas but that has yet to lead to anything relevant.
